# Python - Compare two dictionaries [Match case sensitive values]

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to compare two dictionaries (list containing arrays) in Python.

Here are two dictionaries:

```
tag=[{'Key': 'Base', 'Value': 'ny'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'newyork'}]

filters=[{'Key': 'Name','Value': ['Newyork', 'newyork','NewYork']}]
```

The task here is to compare `filters` dict with `tag` dict.

Following ways I tried which didn't work :

```
>>> tag == filters
False
>>> tag[1] == filters
False
>>> tag[1] == filters[0]
False
```

I want to check if `tag` has an array matching to `filters` it should return `true`.

Probably, it is able to compare the value of `Key`in the array as it has an exact matching string but for `Value` which has same string written in different cases, it doesn't match.

The things I want to cover while comparing:

- comparing it with every array in the dictionary if any array matches should return true
- consider all types of possible cases for `key`and `values`: `'Name','name','NAME'` and `'Newyork', 'newyork','NewYork'`

Any help appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you add more examples and expected outputs ? I don't quite understand what you're comparing exactly ?

Comment: @Deuce I have added snippet from my script. Hope that helps.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't help much. The dictionnaries you give in the beginning of your post don't seem to match the actual dictionnaries you would be getting in your code ? i.e. `filter=[{'Key': ['Keep'],'Values': ['True', 'true','TRUE']}]` from the beginning is different compared to `filters=[{'Name': 'tag:Keep', 'Values': ['True', 'TRUE', 'true']}]` from your snippet. It's really confusing.

Comment: Alors, is `tag=[{'Key': 'Base', 'Value': 'MyImage1'}, {'Key': 'Keep', 'Value': 'True'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'TestBaseImage'}]` actually what you have ? It seems odd ? Why have a dict with {'key': 'key', 'value':'value'} instead of {'key':'value'} ?

Comment: @Deuce I refined the whole question with a more clear example of what I want to do. Hope its clear this time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are quite odd data structures to start with, but I recognize those as the sort of things aws cli/api returns. I bet there's a cli/api way to filter for what you're trying to do, you should really post a question about what you're trying to query from aws ([see](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). But ignoring that for the moment:

Note that `tag` isn't a dictionary, but a list of dictionaries. You need to first pick the dictionary that has `Key:Name` in it.

```
next(element for element in tag if element['Key'] == 'Name')
=> {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'newyork'}
```

Or rather, you want to select the dictionary that has the same `Key:xxx` as your filter.

```
next(element for element in tag if element['Key'] == filters[0]['Key'])
=> {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'newyork'}
```

Now you want to compare the `Value` from selected dictionary with your filter `Value`

```
selectedDict=next(element for element in tag if element['Key'] == filters[0]['Key'])
selectedDict['Value'] in filters[0]['Value']
=> True
```

In one line,

```
next(element for element in tag if element['Key'] == filters[0]['Key'])['Value'] in filters[0]['Value']
=> True
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Indeed, I want to do something with AWS tags actually want to filter them. I already had figured out a solution (long version of it) but I want to understand the other ways I could have done it. I asked this question because I didn't find any proper help on how to do it. Maybe your solution would help people solve such queries in many different ways. :)

Answer (score 0):

This takes your Dictionary's converts them to lower case, discards the extra cases(I.E. NewYork, NEWYORK, ETC. and compares the returned Dictionary's for matches.

```
import re

tag=[{'Key': 'Base', 'Value': 'ny'}, {'Key': 'Name', 'Value': 'newyork'}]
filters=[{'Key': 'Name','Value': ['Newyork', 'newyork','NewYork']}]

def dict_to_lower(dct):
    tmp = []
    for item in dct:
        #check for one value, change to lower case
        if re.search(r'[\,]', str(item['Value'])) is None:
            item['Key'] = str(item['Key']).lower()
            item['Value'] = str(item['Value']).lower()
            tmp.append(item)
        #else multiple values in list, change to lower, discard all but one
        else:
            item['Key'] = str(item['Key']).lower()
            item['Value'] = re.search(r'(\w+)', str(item['Value']).lower()).group(0)
            tmp.append(item)

    dct = tmp


    return dct

def compare_lists(tag, filters):
    #compare tag to filters return matches
    check = set([(d['Key'], d['Value']) for d in filters])
    return [d for d in tag if (d['Key'], d['Value']) in check]

tag = dict_to_lower(tag)
filters = dict_to_lower(filters)

if compare_lists(tag, filters):
    #Rest of your code here
```

Comment: Thanks, Pete for the solution. Your solution will work definitely but I was looking for a more efficient way to solve such problem as I'm using AWS Lambda which has restrictions on the number of characters I can use so the smaller the code the better it is. Anyway, appreciate your help! :)